# How to access method from base application?

Tags: java, android

I extended "Application" class and created custom method "doSomething". I used manifest to setup this class as base class for whole application. Now, how I can access this "doSomething" method from MainActivity?

```
public class App extends Application {

    public void something()
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.test"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT: First, thank you for all answers, but I have to sorry for my input. I forgot to mention, that I would like to access it same way as Override. Why? Because I am going to init something (it takes a few ms) in "App" and only after, I can continue with using those values in MainActivity.**

Right now I use "BaseActivity", which init user access to database. But each activity open "new" connection which seem to be waste of time. I need to login to database only once and use this references for all activities. This is why I create method "dataReady" in "BaseActivity", extend "MainActivity" with "BaseActivity" and overwrite method "dataReady" to init adapter and other stuff.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    void dataReady()
    {

    }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    void dataReady()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple, in your `Main Activity` use `getApplication()` method

```
((App)getApplication()).doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to create `Singleton` and access like

```
private volatile static App applicationInstance;

public static App getInstance() {
    if (applicationInstance == null) {
        synchronized (App.class) {
            if (applicationInstance == null) {
                applicationInstance = new App();
            }
        }
    }

    return applicationInstance;
}
```

Use like

```
App.getInstance().something();
```

I always go with this.

Comment: what is the purpose of checking two times `if (applicationInstance == null) {` one before and after  `synchronized` block?

Answer (score 0):

Application class is also the parent application context. Hence, anywhere you can access `Context`, you can try to access the custom `Application` class.

In below example, `MyApp` extends `Application` and has `doSomething()` method:

```
final Context appCtx = context.getApplicationContext();

if(appCtx instanceof MyApp){
   final MyApp app = (MyApp) appCtx;
   app.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the application instance via getApplication() method. You can cast into App and invoke any public method inside the application class by

```
((App)getApplication()).doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to have an instance of your app ready:

```
private static App sInstance;

public static synchronized App getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
}
```

Then you will be able to do:

```
App.getInstance().something();
```